# Css3 animation scale and translate use maintime

Tags: css, scale, translate-animation

I have some problem with animations. I'm writing steam animation and I need use translate and scale main time. I write some example you can see that it doesn't work. If you have time please help to do it correctly thanks.

html

```
<img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-uU_C0PBe64k/VSd6800h1bI/AAAAAAAAFM8/hp-vH8wT3U4/w63-h57-no/steam.png" />
```

css

```
@mixin steamLeft($speed, $delay) {
    -webkit-animation-name: steamLeft;
    animation-name: steamLeft;
    animation-duration: $speed;
    animation-delay: $delay;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 100px;
    width: 63px;
    height: 57px;
    @include steamLeft(2s,0);
}

@keyframes steamLeft {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0) scale(0);
    }

    10% {
        transform: translateX(10px) scale(0.5);
    }

    20% {
        transform: translateX(20px) scale(1);
    }
}
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/amkrtchyan/npvdtaLu/)

also css write only for firefox on chrom it doesn't work

Comment: Add browser prefixes then it will work http://jsfiddle.net/npvdtaLu/1/

Comment: hm i know about prefixes, i special write only for firefox, the question about scale and translate maintime

Comment: Did you mean to increase delay or something ? its hard to read your mind..